# Why is an If statement considered a function in this loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jslint

I have been building a React app that uses iteration a lot. I am using JSLint and get the annoying warning saying:

> Don't make functions within a loop

On the following loop:

```
if(currentSearch[i].users.length > 0) {
    var matched = false;

    //I hate how JSLint just can't handle setting a variable to true within a function
    //this is loop where I get the warning 
    currentSearch[i].users.some(childUser => {
        if(childUser.id === user.id) {
            return matched = true;
        }
    })
    //^^^^^ Warning

    if(!matched) {
        var alert = new AlertObject(user,currentSearch[i],true,false);
        alerts.push(alert);
    }
}
```

I don't think I set a function in the loop? I am using the array.some function which will break the loop if I return true, which is what I do. I return a variable, declared outside of the loop, as true. This breaks me out of the loop, and allows me to do logic below.

I should also be noted that this is also entirely within a loop, as we are iterating over current search users. I get no runtime or compile errors, and this code works fine, but maybe I am setting myself up for disaster in the future.

Any ideas why I am getting this error? And if I am missing some best practice?

Comment: What a strange way to use `some` :). You don't need mutate a variable outside of the callback. Just use the value returned `const matched = currentSearch[i].users.some(childUser => childUser.id === user.id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in the first line you reference `currentSearch[i]`, because the `[i]` I assume the whole block of code you pasted here is inside some kind of loop, probably a `for`.

Then, you are creating a function for the `Array.some` callback, which triggers the error.

One solution would be to move that callback declaration to be outside the parent loop, but since you are using a variable from the scope, it will require some refactor.

---

**Posible solution**

You can declare a function outside the parent loop (the one outside the code you provided here) that checks for the child user.

```
//Please provide a better name for the function according to the context.
const checkChildUser = function (childUser) {
    return this.id === childUser.id;
};
```

And then pass it to the `Array.some` function you are using:

```
currentSearch[i].users.some(checkChildUser, user);
```

Comment: Ideally I want to keep the variables in the scope they are in, to not complicate things for people who might want to read my code. Would this be considered bad practice if I kept it as it is and just ignored the error?

Comment: @bflynnigan I edited my answer providing a way to solve the problem. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Yes this does work, weirdly though, when I ran the code before I got 408 alert objects built, but when I run with your code I get 411. Sooooo I am going to investigate more, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with React, but this looks like an ES6 arrow function:

```
childUser => { ... }
```

Which would be the equivalent of

```
function (childUser) { ... }
```

Comment: But with the Array.Some() you pass it a fuinction as a parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Plus, it doesn't throw an error when I pass a function as a parameter on the 100 other or so times I call array.Some

Comment: My guess would be that JSLint isn't smart enough to know that this is regular practice with React. There might be some config you could do to stop it complaining about that?

Comment: Yea there is: /*jshint loopfunc: true*/
Although this didn't actually work for me
I want to know why it would throw the error here and not elsewhere

Comment: Careful, yes, it's an arrow function, but it's not the same as declaring a function. Check this https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a

Comment: The warning is about efficiency. It's more efficient to declare the function once, outside the loop, rather than inside it where it will be created with each iteration and slow things down and potentially use more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are providing a function in your `.some()` as a parameter so thats what triggers the warning.

The reason ESLint warns against it

`Writing functions within loops tends to result in errors due to the way the function creates a closure around the loop` - [source](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func)

You can do it like this

```
function compareId(childUser) {
  if (childUser.id === user.id) {
    return true;
  }
}

if (currentSearch[i].users.length > 0) {
  var matched = currentSearch[i].users.some(compareId);

  if (!matched) {
    var alert = new AlertObject(user, currentSearch[i], true, false);
    alerts.push(alert);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should it not be: 
var matched = currentSearch[i].users.some(compareId);

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, the `Don't make functions within a loop` warning is not caused by the `if statement`, but by this following anonymous function:

```
childUser => {
 if(childUser.id === user.id) {
  return matched = true;
 }
}
```

Since you've said that the entire code is within a loop, a new instance of that anonymous function is being created for every iteration. This will affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you create a function that modifies the `matched` variable. This variable is declared with `var`, so it's scope is the whole function, not a single loop iteration. This could lead to surprising results, since functions created in each iteration will actually refer to the *same* variable.

Simply using the value returned by `some()` instead of changing `matched` in the callback (as suggested by Yury Tarabanko) should remove the warning.